# I keep getting an error message that report.cls was not found

Tags: errors

I tried reading older posts but they all seem irrelevant. For some reason when I try to compile ANY document in TeXworks I get the error:

> ```
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
> entering extended mode
> (C:/Users/USER/Documents/ads.tex
> LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
> Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
> abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
> croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
> lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
> ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
>  lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
> german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
> ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
> an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
> ishmax, welsh, loaded.
>
> ! LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not found.
>
> Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
> or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)
>
> Enter file name:
> ```

I compile files that were previously working and get this error. I have had this problem in the past and even though I didn't do anything it was fixed. Now it does it again. I dont understand why. Can someone please help me? The file I was trying to compile that produced the above error was:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

oko

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which installation do you have? Miktex or Texlive? And how did you install it?

Comment: This sounds more like a unreliable Windows installation problem than anything else.  If you have a working LaTeX installation of any kind, it should be able to find the "article" document class.  Re-install MiKTeX and your problem should go away.

Comment: This happens during an update of TeX's directory hash. How about running `texhash` from the command line and trying again?

Comment: I installed MikTex from the website

Comment: Sorry whaaat do you mean by "run texhash from command line"?

Comment: @Werner ^^ For you. I can't help with Windows or I'd answer the query. (I can say, 'run texhash from the command line' but if that's not enough, I can only suggest a saner OS ;).)

Comment: when did you install miktex? (you have a very old system from 2011)

Comment: I downloaded a month ago I dont know why it says 2011

Comment: @and: Run the command cod, which should open up a DOS terminal window. Then type texhash abs press ENTER.

Comment: Miktex seems to be 2.9 in its latest incarnation.  http://miktex.org/

Comment: If you downloaded last month but still get messages from a quite outdated system, then you perhaps have a second (partial) texsystem on your pc. Open a command line, type `echo %path` and hit enter, and then check in the list of pathes if there is more then one miktex related. Check also the path of texworks when you open it (hover over the name in the start menu until the tooltips appear).